# Show that if $x \neq 0$ then $e^x-x-1 \neq 0$ without Taylor series.

Tags: calculus

Show that if $x \neq 0$ then $e^x-x-1 \neq 0$ without Taylor series.

---

If we let $f(x)=e^x-x-1$, the fact that it is monotonically increasing on $[0,\infty)$  and monotonically decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$ allows us to say that $f(x) \geq f(0)=0$. But the trouble in making strict inequality is at the origin where $f'(x)=0$.

To illustrate this trouble consider the function $f$ such that $f(x)=2$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=x^2$ if $x>0$. Clearly then $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$ but yet $f(x)>f(0)$ does not always hold truth if $x>0$, say $x=1$.

---

I'm wondering if perhaps that the fact that our function is strictly increasing on $x>0$ and strictly decreasing on $x<0$ combined with the fact that $f$ is continuous proves the statement we are trying to prove.

Comment: Doesn't $x>0 \implies f(x)>f(0)$ rely on the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$? Which is not the case here

Comment: The "problem" with your second function is that it is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Why do you say that @Taladris. Can you prove that if it is continuous then we do not have that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$f(a) = 0$,
then, by the 
mean value theorem,
there is a
$c$ between
$a$ and $0$
such that
$f'(c) = 0$.

But
$f'(c)
=e^c-1
$
and this is $0$
only for $c = 0$,
and this is not between $0$ and $a$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\exists x_0>0$ s.t. $f(x_0)=0$, then $f$ is null on $[0,x_0]$ (since $f$ is increasing). Now can you finish?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why $f$ is null on that interval.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla well if it wasnt the case, say $\exists 0<x_1 < x_0$ s.t. $f(x_1) > 0$, then $f(x_1) > f(x_0)$ which is a contradiction of the fact that $f$ is monotonically increasing

Answer (score 1):

Use the convex function theory.

Consider the function $f(x) = e^x - x - 1, x \in \mathbb{R}$, since $f''(x) = e^x > 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ is a **strictly** convex function on $\mathbb{R}$, hence the minimum $x = 0$ is unique. In this way you can actually show that $e^x - x - 1 > 0$ unless $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Find extremum: $$f'(x)=e^x-1=0 \Rightarrow x=0.$$
$$f''(1)=e^1>0 \Rightarrow f(1)=e-1 \ (min)$$
and the function is convex and continuous, thus  $f(1)=e-1$ is a global minimum.